# CS50 - PSET3 Run off - trouble understanding the vote function, more specifically what preferences[voter][rank] = i; does

Tags: c, cs50

Im currently doing cs50 and on pset3, i came across this  tough problem set *Runoff* So basically, this is a solution for vote() function that searches for a specific candidate and returns true and records the votes if the candidate is found using a runoff-style election where voters are given preferences in order of ranks, the two-dimensional array *preferences* has already been initialized. Candidates is another array with a list of candidates

```
// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++){
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name,name)==0){
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

just that i'm really confused as to what

```
preferences[voter][rank] = i;
```

does when such a candidate is found/true. What does it mean by  `= i;` everytime the loop runs? Why not `preferences[voter][rank]=candidates[i];`

been struggling with this as I cant really get my head around it, any help would be really appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does it mean by  = i;

It stores the index (read: position) of the candidate in its respective `candidates` array. Later on, you can look up the candidate's name by using this index.

> Why not preferences[voter][rank]=candidates[i];

Because (I assume) `preferences` is a 2-dimensional `int` (or so) array.
Of course, you could use a different type of an array and store (for example) a pointer to the candidate as well.